# asp.net web API HTTP PUT method

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

I have some resource- UserProfile

```
public UserProfile
{
   public string Email{get;set;}
   public string Password{get;set;}
}
```

I want to change Email and Password separatly (only one for user at same time). I have web api controller for example /api/user/123  that handle requests in RESTful style. Follow the RESTful style i should have **one** method **PUT** which update the resource, but i have two task that update the same resource api/user/123. I need to add some feature to PUT request body like
{email:'test@domain.com', **changeType:'email**'} or {password:'12345678',**changeType:'password'** }  to write some  if in my PUT method ? Or there is some other way to update my resource in RESTful style ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options for updating email and password separately.

A) Don't use PUT, use POST

B) Create child resources for updating the individual elements, e.g.

```
PUT /api/user/123/email
```

And

```
PUT /api/user/123/password
```

Comment: Thanks, I've understood B), but I can't understand A) how I can use one method POST to separately update email and  password ?

Comment: You could use POST by putting the details in the body. However, B is more RESTful.

Comment: @MikeDunker More RESTful based on what criteria of REST.  Creating micro resources such as those in example B can make a real mess of caching.  There are pros and cons to both approaches.  "RESTfulness" is not a particularly useful measure.

Answer (score 2):

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage PutProduct(Product p)
{
    Product pro = _products.Find(pr => pr.Id == p.Id);

    if (pro == null)
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

    pro.Id = p.Id;
    pro.Name = p.Name;
    pro.Description = p.Description;

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: An explaination is always better.